# C# Gridview , TableDefinition,type datetime :how to change default mm/dd/year to dd/mm/year?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

SqlDatabase,Gridview,SqlDataSource:

By default in Table Definition, the data type: datetime is mm/dd/year .

Is there any method to make it dd/mm/year ? I can do this in the control of the gridview but the database won't accept it since it's not the default format.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a BoundColumn for your date field, and I assume you know about the DataFormatString property?  Does that not work for you?

If not, you could try harnessing the RowUpdating event to convert your new date value to the right format.